# Was ist "als" in "als Kind" für eine Wortart?

Tags: conjunction

> **Als** Kind habe ich Klavier gespielt.

Könntet Ihr mir bitte erklären, warum "als" hier als eine Konjunktion gilt, wenn kein Fall von Unterordnung vorliegt? Duden gibt ein ähnliches Beispiel an (Punkt 7. zur Einleitung der näheren Erläuterung eines Bezugswortes: *ich habe als Mädchen (in meiner Mädchenzeit, als ich ein Mädchen war) immer davon geträumt*
https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/als_in_Vergleichen

Gilt "als" hier als Konjunktion, weil man "als Kind" zu einem temporalen Nebensatz auffalten könnte (*Als ich Kind war, habe ich Klavier gespielt*.)?
Wenn ich mir jedoch den Teil *als_in_Vergleichen* im oben genannten Link ansehe, werden meine Zweifel noch stärker: Ist das etwa eine komparative Konjunktion? Ein Adverb?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wie auch sonst sehr häufig ist [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/als) hilfreicher als der Duden:

Untern den Bedeutungen steht dort bei Nr. 4:

> als Apposition in Form + Nominativ

Und zu dieser Bedeutung werden auch zwei Beispielsätze angeführt (Hervorhebungen von mir):

> - Er verkleidete sich **als Clown.**
> - **Als Bundespräsident** hatte Horst Köhler besondere Befugnisse.

Und auch die Wortart ist klar: Es handelt sich um eine **Konjunktion.**

---

Das [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/als) ist noch ergiebiger als Wiktionary. Dort werden 5 Bedeutungen aufgelistet, die von dir gesuchte ist gleich die erste, aufgeteilt in 3 Untergruppen, wobei mir am ehesten die Untergruppe a zu passen scheint. Dort stehen unter anderem diese Beispiele:

> er **als Arbeiter**
> die Verdienste Einsteins **als Physiker**
> **als Delegierter** teilnehmen

Achja: Als grammatische Klassifizierung (also als Wortart) nennt auch das DWDS: **Konjunktion**

---

Eine Konjunktion muss übrigens keine Sätze verbinden, sie kann auch einzelne Wörter verbinden:

> in Bausch **und** Bogen
> männlich **oder** weiblich?

Daher ist ein "Auffalten" zu einem Satz gar nicht notwendig, um eine Konjunktion als solche zu klassifizieren. In deinem Beispielsatz stellt das Wort *als* eine Verbindung zwischen *ich* und *Kind* her:

> ich als Kind

Answer (score 0):

'als' wird in einigen Grammatiken zusammen mit "wie" als Gleichsetzungspartikel bezeichnet, was beinah schon eine eigene Wortart ist. In einem Deutsch-als-Fremdsprache-Lehrwerk wird es sogar zu den Präpositionen gezählt (in Menschen A1), was ganz sicher falsch ist. Konjunktionen verbinden Sätze, Satzglieder oder Satzgliedteile miteinander. Das gilt aber nur für die gleichordnenden, die unterordnenden hingegen verbinden Sätze (in der Regel Hauptsätze mit Nebensätzen oder Nebensätzen mit untergeordneten Nebensätzen).
Ich muss sagen, dass Peter und der Wolf bzw. Peter als Wolf für mich schon andere Konstruktionen sind. Wörter oder Satzglieder verbinden: das tun auch Präpositionen, Artikel (Genitivartikel). So ganz befriedigend ist also die Zuordnung zu den gleichordnenden Konjunktionen nicht.

Answer (score 0):

Die *Vergleichspartikeln* "als" und "wie" sind ein Sonderfall der Konjunktion, weil sie folgende Eigenschaften mit ihr teilen:

- Sie regieren keinen Kasus (sind damit keine Präposition)
- Ihnen folgt ein einziges Satzglied, eine einzige Ergänzung, mit der sie zusammen verschoben werden.

Sie leiten aber keinen Nebensatz ein und verbinden damit nur ein Satzglied mit dem Rest des Satzes.