# What kind of conjunction is "als"?

Tags: conjunction

> **Als** Kind habe ich Klavier gespielt.

This question is actually a follow-up to: [Was ist "als" in "als Kind" für eine Wortart?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/59467/was-ist-als-in-als-kind-f%c3%bcr-eine-wortart).
It was said that **als** is a *conjunction*. There are, however, two types of conjunctions: *coordinating* and *subordinating*, and I am not sure which type **als** is, since there is no verb in the *als*-phrase.

Should I treat the phrase *Als Kind* as ellipsis of ***Als** ich Kind war*, and therefore categorize the conjunction as subordinating? Or should I rather categorize it as coordinating because of the lack of the verb?

Comment: In this case it's a (timeline) comparison. The ellipsis is: Als Kind _(,- und nicht jetzt -,)_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ok, but what about hypothetical cases? "Als Kunde wäre ich verärgert, als Investor bin ich zufrieden."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the point of assigning words to parts of speech is to be able to predict how the word behaves, calling *als* in uses such as the one you mentioned a *conjunction* is not helpful.

Conjunctions are words that at least potentially link clauses to other clauses. The distinction between subordinating and coordinating conjunctions is then based on the form the clause containing the conjunction takes. Subordinating conjunctions occur in a fixed position at the beginning of subordinate clauses; coordinating conjunctions occur in a position that is further to the left still.

> Sie wollte wissen, wann der Kurs beginnt **und ob** er eine Gebühr kostet.

In this example, *ob* links the subordinate clause to the main clause and *und* links the two subordinate clauses to each other.

However, *als* in your example does not connect two clauses. Rather, *als Kind* functions as an [adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_(grammar)) or modifier. The meaning is not always temporal:

> Als Kind kann man sich damit trösten, dass man irgendwann erwachsen ist.
> Man hat auch als Kind Rechte.

Personally, I consider preposition the closest traditional part of speech. However, unlike prepositions, words such as *als* and *wie* do not govern case; rather, they agree with the phrase they modify (if they modify a noun phrase).

> Sie vererbte **ihm** als jung**em** Mann ein Vermögen.
> **Er** erbte als jung**er** Mann ein Vermögen.

A modern term for words such as *als* and *wie* is *Adjunktor* (see, for instance, [Grammis](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/9)).

Answer (score 2):

The categorization between *nebenordnenden* and *unterordnenden* conjunctions in German is simply:

> Die nebenordnenden Konjunktionen verbinden zwei Hauptsätze, zwei Nebensätze oder zwei Satzteile miteinander

> Die unterordnenden Konjunktionen verbinden einen Hauptsatz mit einem Nebensatz

In your example, there is no subclause, so the answer should obviously be "nebenordnend". In your re-formed phrase, there is a subclause, so it's "unterordnend". This example also shows how useful these categories are in German.